# How to know if a is variables defined in scala on Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I use Zeppelin and I'm trying to check if a variable is defined (We generally define a variable as either var or val) on scala environment or not. Eg: I want to know if my scala environment (in other paragraphs) has a *score* defined or not to prevent me from overriding it every time I run the same code paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
But you could define your *score* variable in another previous paragraph
and then use it in the following paragraph.

This way, score will be "overrided" only when you re-run the first paragraph, not the second one.

Example:

First paragraph:

```
var score = 0
```

Second paragraph:

```
score += 1
print(score)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do the same thing as you suggested already but the main issue with me is that I run the previous paragraph regularly as part of loops between paragraphs.